# Three specific letters random generated from array

Tags: java, arrays

I really want to make a class that can generate 3 random letters with an array 12 times. I'm having some trouble with random requesting int instead of char. Thanks for help! :)

Comment: If you're "having some trouble" that suggests you've got some code that doesn't quite work - so please show that code, and give details of what's not working.

Comment: What does "random requesting int instead of char" mean???

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to define an alphabet `String alphabet = "AaBb..."`, which contains all valid characters. Then your code can look like this:

```
public char generateRandomLetterFromAlphabet(String alphabet) {
    Random random = new Random();
    return alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
}
```

Here, `nextInt(alphabet.length())` returns a *random* index between zero and the length of the alphabet string, so a *random* character of your alphabet is returned by `generateRandomLetterFromAlphabet`. Note that `Random` generates *pseudo-random* numbers.

Of course, your alphabet can be defined by an array, too. Here you have a function to generate a specified number of random characters from an alphabet as character array:

```
public char[] generateRandomLettersFromAlphabet(char[] alphabet,
        int numberOfLetters) {

    if (numberOfLetters < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Number of letters must be strictly positive.");
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    char[] randomLetters = new char[numberOfLetters];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++) {
        randomLetters[i] = alphabet[random.nextInt(alphabet.length)];
    }

    return randomLetters;

}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a general example for `char` arrays.

Comment: There are 50442 letters scattered all over the codepoint number-space so an alphabet is an excellent idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASCII codes to convert a random integer number to the correspondent char. More info about ascii at: http://www.ascii-code.com/

This simple method outputs a char based on a random integer between 65 (capital A) and 90 (capital Z).

```
public char randomChar(){
    Random r = new Random();
    int num = r.nextInt(26) + 65;
    return (char) num;
}
```

Now you can tweak this method to your own purposes.

Comment: `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, not an ASCII code unit. (UTF-16 is an encoding of the Unicode character set.) 65 is indeed the one UTF-16 code unit for the codepoint [Latin Capital Letter A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0041/index.htm) but it is more easily understood as `'A'`.